# Expo: Using AuthSession unable to open Web Browser for Authentication

Tags: react-native, expo, openid-connect, openid

I am using Expo in managed workflow and Expo Go as the debug app (on Android). SDK version is 46. I try to authenticate against an OpenID Connect service (provided by a Keycloak instance). I used the documentation and examples found on the Expo docs but wasn't able to get it running with some weird errors.

Here's my code:

```
WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const useProxy = false;

const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
    useProxy
});

export default function LoginIDPScreen({ navigation }: Props) {

    const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery('http://192.168.178.131:8080');

    // Create and load an auth request
    const [request, result, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest({
        clientId: 'titan-mobile',        
        redirectUri,
        scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
    }, discovery);

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Button title="Login!" disabled={!request} onPress={() => promptAsync({ useProxy }) } />
          {result && <Text>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</Text>}
        </View>
      );
}
```

Running this (hitting the "Login" button), it results in the following error:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Call to function 'ExpoWebBrowser.openBrowserAsync' has been rejected.
→ Caused by: No matching browser activity found
```

I tried to open a web browser manually using `WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://expo.dev')` an that works fine, so I guess it's not actually about finding the browser activity.

When I read out the `redirectUri` it comes out as `exp://192.168.178.130:19000`, which I found weird as well, but given it can not even open the IDP for authentication, I think this is not the issue.

I intentionally switched off the proxy, afaik the proxy does not work with development envs. Enabling the proxy results in another error:

```
ERROR  Error: Cannot use the AuthSession proxy because the project full name is not defined. Prefer AuthRequest (with the useProxy option set to false) in combination with an Expo Development Client build of your application. To continue using the AuthSession proxy, specify the project full name (@owner/slug) using the projectNameForProxy option.
```

Adding `projectNameForProxy` to the arguments for `promptAsync()` does not work and looking at the documentation for AuthRequest, it strongly recommends not using it and using AuthSession instead..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: found the issue. It was caused by the discovery failing silently. The example code is not well engineered here. There should be a check (even in the example) that detects errors when doing the discovery part.

If you are encountering this, make sure the actual endpoint URL delivered to the auth mechanism is actually set from the discovery.

Comment: Can you provide your code, so we can see what you are trying to say?

Comment: Please can you provide a code example to explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In My case it was like missing scheme. After adding it worked in expo go

```
{
"expo": {
  "scheme": "your-app-slug"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help. I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding intent filters to Expo's app.json config.

```
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/favicon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  "intentFilters": [
    { 
      "autoVerify": true, 
      "action": "VIEW", 
      "data": { 
        "scheme": "msauth", 
        "host": "com.name.proj" 
      }, 
      "category": ["BROWSABLE", "DEFAULT"] 
    }
  ],
  "icon": "./assets/favicon.png",
  "package": "com.name.proj",
  "permissions": [
    "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
    "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
  ]
},
```